# Show hidden text in HTML page

Tags: html

What code I have to add to my HTML page if I want to see hidden text related to short paragraph? Here is an example:

a) is what you see when you open web page
b) is what you see when you click link "more"

a) http://www.ozdravimo.info/xx.html 
b) http://www.ozdravimo.info/yy.html

Comment: Sorry this question is considered off-topic because it is JavaScript/HTML (programming related). It's best suited on Stack Overflow but in the currently format is unlikely to be accepted. Please visit Stack Overflow and check their rules before reposting.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use javascript with your HTML.

There is a very well done answer over at StackOverflow ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12308064/2268476)) which should get you on the right track and help you to get the outcome you desire.

Here is the example that was shown.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="text-container">
    <h1>Title goes here</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    <div class="content hideContent">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
        <p>Some more text</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Some more text</li>
            <li>Some more text</li>
            <li>Some more text</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="show-more">
        <a href="#">Show more</a>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
.hideContent {
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 1em;
    height: 2em;
}

.showContent {
    line-height: 1em;
    height: auto;
}
```

> I'm assuming setting the line-height will ensure it is the same in all
>   browsers. I'm not 100% certain on that though.
>
> I attached a click event to the "show more" link which switches the
>   classes on the div using [jQueryUI switchClass()](http://jqueryui.com/switchClass/):

```
$(".show-more a").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this); 
    var $content = $this.parent().prev("div.content");
    var linkText = $this.text().toUpperCase();    

    if(linkText === "SHOW MORE"){
        linkText = "Show less";
        $content.switchClass("hideContent", "showContent", 400);
    } else {
        linkText = "Show more";
        $content.switchClass("showContent", "hideContent", 400);
    };

    $this.text(linkText);
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Wpn94/)** - show more / show less and applying line-height and animation

> The above code is an example only but should get you started into the
>   right direction.

Answer (score 1):

While @Analog's answer is correct, it would be worth investigating [JQuery](http://www.jquery.com) which has vast libraries that will do this for you and also add some further functionality.